# How to select Top Donors filtered by Contribution source

Tags: contributions, reports

I would like to run a donor report to see how much our congregants have donated over the time we have been with Shuilsuite.

I see the report called 'top donors' which is exactly what I am looking for.  However, the way we identify whether or not it is a donation is by using the 'source' of the transaction as we reference it 'Donation'. This filter does not exist, so I am unable to use this report. Can you please suggest a way to export these transactions or run a report so that I can identify the person's name, pledge amount, confirmed receipt, and status?

Thank you

Michael

Comment: i don't know what you mean by shuilsuite - can you clarify

Comment: I think you will need to contact shuilshuite directly - since they control your CiviCRM instance - they can help - they may have several reports set up along with Financial Types. Only they can tell you how to best pull reports on their system.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to install the [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields/summary-fields) extension and see if that helps you get the numbers you need

Answer (score 0):

Try Contributions > Find Contributions  You can set a date range, and source. With the results, check all, and under Actions select Export. This will give you the detail for each donor rather than the total. But if you do not have 1000s of donors, it should not take to long to have Excel sum them.

Or can you use Financial Type instead of Source? Or is Source your only differentiation? If you can use Financial Type, then most Contribution Reports will get you the results you want.